# Double-formula for the expectation

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ a probability space and $X$ a continuous random variable with density $f(x)$. In probability theory, how to prove that
\begin{gather*}
\int_{\Omega} X(\omega)dP(\omega) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} xf(x)dx.
\end{gather*}

Perhaps, do we need to use a change of variables or space formula ?

Thanks for your help.

Marcus

Comment: Huh? MCrassus, that is precisely the change of variables formula, is it not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, change of variables is a good idea:

$$\int_{\Omega} X(\omega) \, d\mathbb{P}(\omega) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x \, d\mathbb{P}_X(x)$$

where $\mathbb{P}_X$ denotes the image measure (pushforward measure/distribution) of $X$ with respect to $\mathbb{P}$.

Comment: Oh yes I see.. Then I think that you should finish the proof with the Radon-Nikodym derivative, right ? I am sorry to ask you this but could you explain me exactly the theorem ? Maybe, citing a version of it and a simple example for density functions of real random variables ? Thank you so much.

Comment: @MCrassus What do you mean by "simple example for density functions"? Do you want to see an application of the theorem for a concrete density function?

Comment: Yes, exactly because actually I do not understand very well this theorem. I think, we have to use it to conclude. Does it really explain the fact that we can replace $dP_X(x)$ by $f(x)dx$ ?

Comment: @MCrassus No, it doesn't. That we can replace $d\mathbb{P}_X(x)$ by $f(x) \, dx$ follows from the very definition of $X$ having a density.

Comment: Huh? saz, MCrassus' statement is precisely the change of variable, is it not?

Comment: @BCLC For me "change of variables" is something else.

Comment: saz, oh wait I think I got it: Change of variable formula is using law of a random variable? $\mathscr L_X(t)$?

Comment: @BCLC For any random variable $X$ it holds that $\int_{\Omega} f(X(\omega)) \, d\mathbb{P}(\omega) = \int f(x) \, d\mathbb{P}_X(x),$$ I know the statement under the name "transformation theorem" ... but if you call it "change of variables", then so be it.